# Clojure: Is there a way to remove a key but keep its values

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I need some help with a pickle. I have the below map

```
    (def my-list 
{:data-0
  {:a1 ;;this is the value for :ward-room
            {:type "Specialist"
            :name "Dr Spongebob"
            :illness "dehydration"
            :ward-room "a1"}}
:data-1
  {:b5
      {:type "GP"
        :name "Dr Patrick"
        :illness "fishy eyes"}
        :ward-room "b5"}})
```

I want to transform this into a map such as below

```
(def my-new-list 
{:data-0
            {:type "Specialist"
            :name "Dr Spongebob"
            :illness "dehydration"
            :ward-room "a1"}
:data-1
      {:type "GP"
        :name "Dr Patrick"
        :illness "fishy eyes"}
        :ward-room "b5"}})
```

I couldn't figure out how to do this so I've tried using `seq` and then `flatten` but have not had success. Im not too sure how to get started Solving this problem. I would really appreciate a little help

Comment: are you sure the data should be formed this way? since `:ward-room` appears on different levels in `:data-0` and `data-1`

Comment: I just cannonballed into the [`defrecord`](https://www.braveclojure.com/multimethods-records-protocols/#Records) pool myself, but I suspect this is a perfect use case for records (uniformity, performance, etc.).

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 2):

considering corrected structure, with `:ward-room` having the same nesting level for both entries:

```
(def my-list 
  {:data-0
   {:a1 ;;this is the value for :ward-room
    {:type "Specialist"
     :name "Dr Spongebob"
     :illness "dehydration"
     :ward-room "a1"}}
   :data-1
   {:b5
    {:type "GP"
     :name "Dr Patrick"
     :illness "fishy eyes"
     :ward-room "b5"}}})
```

there are some options:

first of all you could use `reduce-kv`, remapping to new vals:

```
(reduce-kv
 (fn [acc k v] (assoc acc k (val (first v))))
 {}
 my-list)

;; {:data-0
;; {:type "Specialist",
;;  :name "Dr Spongebob",
;;  :illness "dehydration",
;;  :ward-room "a1"},
;; :data-1
;; {:type "GP",
;;  :name "Dr Patrick",
;;  :illness "fishy eyes",
;;  :ward-room "b5"}}
```

or you could use `zipmap` to zip keys with new vals:

```
(zipmap (keys my-list)
        (map (comp val first val) my-list))
```

also there is a nice way to do it with functional composition:

```
(into {} (map (juxt key (comp val first val))) my-list)
```

Another approach is to splice the entries for every internal map at the upper level. This would also work for 'malformed' data, like yours:

```
(def my-list 
  {:data-0
   {:a1 ;;this is the value for :ward-room
    {:type "Specialist"
     :name "Dr Spongebob"
     :illness "dehydration"
     :ward-room "a1"}}
   :data-1
   {:b5
    {:type "GP"
     :name "Dr Patrick"
     :illness "fishy eyes"}
    :ward-room "b5"}})


(defn lift-entries [old-entries]
  (into {} (mapcat #(if (map? (val %))
                      (val %)
                      [%]))
        old-entries))

(zipmap (keys my-list) (map lift-entries (vals my-list)))

;; {:data-0
;;  {:type "Specialist",
;;   :name "Dr Spongebob",
;;   :illness "dehydration",
;;   :ward-room "a1"},
;;  :data-1
;;  {:type "GP",
;;   :name "Dr Patrick",
;;   :illness "fishy eyes",
;;   :ward-room "b5"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your data sample had a cut/paste error.  Here is a simple answer:

```
(def my-data
  {:data-0 {:a1 {:type      "Specialist"
                 :name      "Dr Spongebob"
                 :illness   "dehydration"
                 :ward-room "a1"}}
   :data-1 {:b5 {:type      "GP"
                 :name      "Dr Patrick"
                 :illness   "fishy eyes"
                 :ward-room "b5"
                 }}})

(defn delete-intermediate-level
  [data]
  (into {}
    (for [[k1 v1] data]
      [k1 (into {}
            (for [[k2 v2] v1]
              v2))])))
```

with result:

```
(delete-intermediate-level my-data) => 
    {:data-0
     {:type "Specialist",
      :name "Dr Spongebob",
      :illness "dehydration",
      :ward-room "a1"},
     :data-1
     {:type "GP",
      :name "Dr Patrick",
      :illness "fishy eyes",
      :ward-room "b5"}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If `my-list` is supposed to be defined as

```
(def my-list 
  {:data-0
     {:a1 ;;this is the value for :ward-room
       {:type "Specialist"
        :name "Dr Spongebob"
        :illness "dehydration"
        :ward-room "a1"}}
   :data-1
     {:b5
       {:type "GP"
        :name "Dr Patrick"
        :illness "fishy eyes"
        :ward-room "b5"}}})
```

(that is, if we include the `:ward-room` key and value in the `:b5` map rather than having it floating around on the loose) then the quickest way I can see to do this is:

```
(zipmap (keys my-list) (map #(first (vals %)) (vals my-list)))
```

It we wrap the above in a `(pprint...)` form it returns

```
{:data-0
 {:type "Specialist",
  :name "Dr Spongebob",
  :illness "dehydration",
  :ward-room "a1"},
 :data-1
 {:type "GP",
  :name "Dr Patrick",
  :illness "fishy eyes",
  :ward-room "b5"}}
```

### EDIT

Or if you prefer it in thread-last form you can use

```
(->> my-list
  (vals)
  (map #(first (vals %)))
  (zipmap (keys my-list)))
```